# Finding a way to reuse my function that varies in one small way

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, anonymous-function, code-reuse

So I am writing a C# application, using .net/c# 4.0
I have a method which takes in a custom type and a dictionary.
I reuse this for a variety of things but for some reason I cannot think of a way to encapsulate the logic.  The problem is this line

```
    if (FastIntParse.FastParse(_dict[_Rule.Key].hourly_data[a].PropertyA) > 
_Rule.Value)
```

In another use it may be

```
    if (FastIntParse.FastParse(_dict[_Rule.Key].hourly_data[a].PropertyB) > 
_Rule.Value)
```

The only thing that varies in the various cases is the Property I am using to compare to the rule value.  For some reason I cannot think of a way to reuse it because I don't have the value to pass in to some function since the value is derived IN the function.  How can I write a function to abstract away it's need to know which value it needs to derive and pass that information in ie pass it which property it will need to check and not the value of said property.

```
    int a;
    for (int z= 0;z<=2;z++)
    {
    a = (z * z) * 24;
    for (; (a%24) <= _Rule.AlertEndTime; a++)
    {
        if (FastIntParse.FastParse(_dict[_Rule.Key].hourly_data[a].PropertyA) >
 _Rule.Value)
        {

            EnqueueRuleTrigger(_Rule);
            break;
        }
    }
    }
```

I keep rewriting this method inline wherever I need it with the proper property.... this is obviously quite wasteful and any change needs to be made in many places.
Thanks in advance

Comment: In case I am not clear, I don't even have the object reference for the property outside of the loop.  I'd like to encapsulate something that contains the loop logic [which doesn't change] along with the ability to supply a custom property to the method.  Thing if I have 4 conditions that are precisely the same except which property they evaluate so I have just been copy and pasting this entire code and changing the property reference.  Even worse each of those 4 have 3 variants, one where the if uses a >, a < and an = So I really have this method slightly modified 12 times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Expression and then pull out the property within the method, then use reflection to tie this up to the object within the method

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<PropertyBag> bags = new List<PropertyBag>()
                                     {
                                         new PropertyBag() {Property1 = 1, Property2 = 2},
                                         new PropertyBag() {Property1 = 3, Property2 = 4}
                                     };

        Runme(x => x.Property1, bags);
        Runme(x => x.Property2, bags);

        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    public static void Runme(Expression<Func<PropertyBag, int>> expression, List<PropertyBag> bags)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        var prop = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;

        bags.ForEach( bag => 
                Console.WriteLine(prop.GetValue(bag, null))
            );
    }
}


public class PropertyBag
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

to solve the problem with access to different properties and with the use of different boolean-function (<, >, ==) you could use delegates like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    delegate bool CompareFunction(Fii test, Foo item);

    class Program
    {
        static List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>() {
            new Foo() { PropertyA = 0, PropertyB = 9 },
            new Foo() { PropertyA = 1, PropertyB = 10 }
        };
        static Fii test = new Fii() { PropertyA = 1 };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bar(list, delegate(Fii item1, Foo item2) { return item2.PropertyA < item1.PropertyA; });
            Bar(list, delegate(Fii item1, Foo item2) { return item2.PropertyB > item1.PropertyA; });
            Bar(list, delegate(Fii item1, Foo item2) { return item2.PropertyA == item1.PropertyA; });
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Bar(List<Foo> list, CompareFunction cmp)
        {
            foreach (Foo item in list)
                if (cmp(test, item))
                    Console.WriteLine("true");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("false");
        }
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public int PropertyA { get; set; }
        public int PropertyB { get; set; }
    }

    class Fii
    {
        public int PropertyA { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your function take a lambda argument and pass it `_ => _.PropertyA`, `_ => _.PropertyB` etc.:

```
void CheckAndEnqueueRulesByProperty (Func<YourObject, string> propertyGetter)
{
    ...
    if (FastIntParse.FastParse (propertyGetter (
            _dict[_Rule.Key].hourly_data[a])) > _Rule.Value)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If you have many types of objects to check with the same logic, make this function generic.

Comment: I can't access _ until I am in the loop because PropertyA and PropertyB are properties of an object in an array[In a dictionary] who's index I don't know till I am in the loop.  This entire thing is a "function" I keep pasting inline.  I want to create a function out of this where I can basically tell it to use a property for an object who I don't have a reference to yet.  That property reference will have to be passed in from the caller.  If your answer covered this sorry I didn't quite get it as I am somewhat new to Lambdas....